# get a new copy of a global variable in a jQuery Call

Tags: jquery, variables

Trying to edit an ID with a variable, and it's calling the same value for the variable each time even though the variable is changing:

Ok, I'm messing around with code to do a drag and drop from one section to another, where it will drop a cloned copy of the original in the drop section (clone/append). If you click on it, it will clone/append a div section containing a form. I want to change the form ID to be unique, by having it be changed to a static string + a variable. After it does the clone, it should increment the variable so that the next time a different copy is made it will get a new form ID.

What SEEMS to be happening is that it works just fine the first time the code runs it gets the variable and appends it on to the static string, but when it is called a second time for a new clone, instead of getting the current value of the global variable, it uses the same value that it had last time. So first call would result in RSS0, and second call would ALSO result in RSS0 even though the formID variable is now at 1 - I expected it to be RSS1 and am VERY confused as to why it isn't.

The variable IS updating properly, because I tracked that using chrome's inspect element (scripts tab, watch expressions) tool, and when I make a different call for a different object being cloned, it takes the current value of the global variable - for the first call, then it does the same thing and is 'stuck' on its initial value at the time of the first call.

I tried going through javascript directly rather than using jQuery to change the ID, and the first time it works correctly, the second time the second clone has the same ID as the first clone, and it 'properly' changes the ORIGINAL - I'm doing a getElementById for this one, and pulling up the first match (the original is listed near the bottom of the page) to have the ID be changed.

Ok, now that I've explained what I'm trying to do and what seems to be actually happening, let me put up my code and maybe someone can tell me how I can fix this so that each form has a unique id....

```
var formID = 0; //used to make each form have its own unique ID

<!-- code section removed - above = global variable,
below is within some other stuff but working 'fine' -->

$(".draggable").click(function()
{
//first check if it doesn't already have #testContents, then check if it is in the copy area
if(!$(this).is(':has(.dragContents)') && $(this).parent().hasClass('copyArea'))
{
    //if it doesn't already have this and is in the correct spot, append a new copy of the appropriate type

    switch( $(this).html() ) //use the html contents of the item to determine which one to add
    {
                        case "RSS":
                            $("#RSScontents").clone().appendTo(this);
                            //document.getElementById("RSS").id = "RSS"+formID;
                            $(this).find("#RSS").attr("id","RSS"+formID);
                            formID++;
                            break;
                        case "Advertisement":
                            $("#drag2contents").clone().appendTo(this);
                            $(this).find("#advert").attr("id","advert"+formID);
                            formID++;
                            break;
```

and the div tag that is being cloned then modified so that you can see the form that I'm working with:

```
<div id="RSScontents" class="dragContents" style="width:380px; padding-left:2px; margin:5px;">
This is the RSS information section
<form id="RSS" method="post">
    RSS Feed URL: <input type="text" name="rssFeedURL" size=35 /><br />
    RSS Feed Title: <input type="text" name="rssFeedTitle" size=35 /><br />
    <input type=button name="rsssave" value="Save"><input type=button name="rssdelete" class="delete" value="Delete">
</form>
```

Comment: tough to do without working code..can you post a jsfiddle?

Comment: http://josh.gotomydemo.com/dragndrop

that's the page that I've got the code on atm - because of the includes to get the jquery UI stuff (draggable/droppable) working I'm not certain how to do the jsfiddle - if you inspect the code you can see what's happening though, that's how I've been debugging it.

Answer (score 0):

try changing

```
$(this).find("#RSS").attr("id","RSS"+formID);
```

to

```
if (formID == 0) {
    $(this).find("#RSS").attr("id","RSS"+formID);
}
else {
$(this).find("#RSS"+(formID - 1)).attr("id","RSS"+formID);
}
```

~Lyn Headley

actual fix:

```
if (formID == 0) {
    $(this).find("#RSS").attr("id","RSS"+formID);
}
else {
$(this).find("#RSS0").attr("id","RSS"+formID);
}
```

because for some reason after the original is cloned, it keeps cloning the first clone (which is changed to RSS0)...don't ask me why though ~Adarajin

Comment: ok, #1 = RSS0, #2 = RSS1, and #3...goes back to RSS0, same with #4. Any idea why this isn't properly updating? Cause it LOOKS like it should work so it's really got me baffled... I appreciate your taking the time to help me btw :-)

Comment: actually, looking over my code again, I'm kind of confused why #2 is working (and why #3/4 are coming up with RSS0 instead of just RSS) because each time I'm making a fresh clone of #RSSContents which has the form #RSS inside of it, then changing that fresh clone... wouldn't 1-1 = 0 rather than empty for the second one? or is it for some reason cloning the first clone, rather than the original even though I clearly said to clone the original?...

Comment: I see it. $("#RSScontents").clone().appendTo(this); is creating many elements with the id #RSSContents.  So you end up cloning different divs each time, with different #RSSN subelements. To fix, identify #RSScontents in another way.

Comment: Ok, I got it working, apparently after it clones the original, it clones the first clone for some reason rather than the original again (and reading through the code I have no clue why it's doing this but that's what the results are telling me...) My fix was to take your suggested fix and make it $(this).find("#RSS0") for the else, and it works like a charm. The only issue is now I need to use a different variable for other things I'm copying because if it doesn't start at 0 it doesn't work.... but at least it's working and that's not a huge change.  Again, thank you for the help.

Comment: it should only be creating one copy of the original at a time and then I'm specifying the clone by saying $(this).find("#RSS") where 'this' is the first/outer cloned object, and then there is only one instance of the cloned div containing the form #RSS within that which I immediately change to be something new/unique so that when I am looking at the page as a whole it is unique...

Comment: because there are multiple elements with the id #RSScontents, the call to $("#RSScontents").clone() will not clone the same 'original' every time.

Comment: yeah, I just broke it again but at least I understand what you are saying now - it's looking for the first match of RSScontents and since my original is at the bottom of the page, if I have a clone closer to the top it will find that one instead. The good news is that I understand what is happening and can now go fix it (scurries off to fix his code)

Comment: ok, fixed and I haven't managed to break it again (yet...) - the final solution: add in a second line just above the line to change the RSS id changing the RSSContents id (of the clone) to something else. Thank you very much for your help and your patience with me.